# Titre de sejour

Tags: france, refusal, asylum, nigerian-citizens

I am a Nigerian citizen and I came to France illegally.  I was refused asylum.  For five years now I have being renewing my one year card. I want to get the ten years card. The law said if you have stayed five years in France you can get the ten years resident card.  What do I need to do to get the ten years card?

Comment: You might get more valid informations here :http://www.lacimade.org/la-cimade-english/

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to have overlooked is that you must have resided in France legally.

The [Service-Public.fr](https://www.service-public.fr/) portal states that the card for **résident de longue durée - UE** can be issued to a foreigner who is not a national of a European country, provided that they are residing in France **"legally** and continuously for at least the past 5 years."

Only the authorities can determine whether you are now considered eligible, and you [apply for the card](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F17359) with the prefecture or sub-prefecture of your residence, within 2 months before the expiry date of your current residence permit.